# Is there any "Analyze and Code Cleanup" tool for .NET project in VS Code or .NET CLI?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core, dotnet-cli

In Visual Studio 2022, there is a `Analyze and Code Cleanup` feature which is really good.

[image: Analyze and Code Cleanup]

I'd like to know that is there any equivalent tool I can use in VS Code or in .NET CLI or in MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of those, I have used *[dotnet-format](https://github.com/dotnet/format)* and heard about *[ReSharper Command Line Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReSharper_Command_Line_Tools.html#install-and-use-resharper-command-line-tools-as-net-core-tools)* those are being distributed as a *[dotnet-tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools)*.

There is even a ready to use [github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dotnet-format) for *dotnet-format* and it is being configured through *[editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/)* so there is no problem at all to integrate it in a CI\CD pipelines.